# Google Tag Manager - all Variables become 'undefined' after an event push

Tags: google-tag-manager

We are using Google Tag Manager on a React app

Recently we noticed that in the Google Tag Manager Tag Assistant, on a particular page on the site, following this dataLayer push, all of our GTM Variables become `undefined`.

This affects every single variable from here on, and includes all variable types - Custom JavaScript, URL, Auto-Event, 1st-party Cookies, Lookup Table, etc. This applies to this event and all events following it on one particular page.

```
dataLayer.push({event: "historyChange_datalayerUpdate", gtm.uniqueEventId: 4})
```

This push happens as part of code which intercepts the `dataLayer.push` function in order to push this event in certain circumstances (related to history changes with React Router). I'm not totally sure why it works in this exact way as I didn't write it.

This event is sent on many of our pages, but it's only one particular page which displays the behaviour of the variables being undefined after this particular push.

There is nothing in the Errors tab in Tag Assistant.

What I don't understand is what could cause all the variables, even the built-in ones, to become undefined. I'd understand why we'd have issues with incorrect data layer variables themselves, but this issue feels like something which is happening more internally to Tag Manager which I'm not sure how to even start debugging. I couldn't find any examples of people with the same problem, or documentation about this issue. Any ideas?

This is the order in which Events happen when the page is loaded, which I thought could possibly be relevant

```
20 optimize.activate

19 optimize.callback

18 optimize.callback

17 optimize.activate

16 Scroll Depth

15 Scroll Depth

14 Scroll Depth

13 Window Loaded

12 DOM Ready a

11 OptanonLoaded

10 OneTrustLoaded

9 OneTrustGroupsUpdated

8 Message

7 Message

6 historyChange_datalayerUpdate <--- Problematic event

5 Message

4 pageview

3 Container Loaded S

2 Consent Initialization S

1 Consent
```